# pytest can't load test modules with __init__.py

Tags: python, pytest

When using pytest to run a specific test, I get the following error:

```
>>> pytest test/test_app.py
ImportError while importing test module '/home/connesy/code/test/test_app.py'.
Traceback:
test/test_app.py:3: in <module>
    import __init__
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__init__'
```

My code is structured like this:

```
├── src
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── conftest.py  # Empty
│   ├── app.py
│   ├── server.py
├── test
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── test_app.py
│   ├── test_server.py
```

Each test has `import __init__` at the top, and `__init__` adds `src` to `sys.path`.

I need to be able to import and run tests from `server.py`, so `test` needs to be a package. How can I run a specific test with pytest with this structure?

Comment: There's no such thing as `import __init__`. `__init__` file basically makes your package folder into a module itself.

Comment: What do you mean "no such thing"? I have `sys.path.insert(1, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')))` in my `__init__.py`, and `import __init__` in all my `test_*.py` scripts, so that I can do `from src.app import run` and such.

Comment: Again: ` __init__` file basically makes your package folder into a module itself. This means you would import it using package name (NOT as `import __init__`) but I don't know how it works with root-level packages - theoretically it should be `import test` (test is folder name == package name, init file makes it importable, see?)

Comment: Sure, but I can't very well put `import test` in `test/test_app.py`.

Comment: As I said, I don't know how it works for root-level packages. Nor for importing package inside its module. It's just not how `__init__` file normally works - init file should import modules, not the other way around. It's how package is seen outside, not literal init for elements inside it.

Comment: If you want to do it semi-correctly, don't do `import __init__` but import all tests **in** the init file and execute them from there.

Comment: Because using the init file like you want might later result in circular dependencies if you want to use init file correctly later.